# SQL Combine multiple row fields into 1 record based on different field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table (columns and records truncated for clarity):

```
StartHour WorkstationName
--------- ---------------
4         Wigets1
19        Wigets2
```

and I would like to have a 1-record result with just the values from `StartHour` for these two rows, so my result would be

```
Wigets1   Wigets2
--------- ---------
4         19
```

and I have this query right now:

```
SELECT Wigets1, Wigets2
FROM (SELECT * FROM InspectorApp 
WHERE WorkstationName IN ('Wigets1', 'Wigets2')) innerselect 
PIVOT(MAX(StartHour) FOR WorkstationName IN ([Wigets1], [Wigets2])) pvt
```

but I get a result of

```
EarlyPipe LgLnStart
--------- ---------
NULL      19
4         NULL
```

How can I get rid of the `NULL`s here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pivot` is finicky.  Just choose the columns you need in the subquery:

```
SELECT Wigets1, Wigets2
FROM (SELECT WorkstationName, StartHour
      FROM InspectorApp 
      WHERE WorkstationName IN ('Wigets1', 'Wigets2')
     ) innerselect 
PIVOT(MAX(StartHour) FOR WorkstationName IN ([Wigets1], [Wigets2])) pvt;
```

PS.  Another reason why I prefer using conditional aggregation for pivoting.

Comment: Beautiful! Works perfectly. (Will accept the answer in 10 minutes )